# Using Kafka with Android

Tags: java, android, apache-kafka

I am trying to do a sample application with kafka to showcase it's streaming capabilities. Here is exactly what I want to do:

1. Create an Android Application to Send Data to Kafka Topics through API's.
2. Make API's publish it to the topic.
3. Write a Streaming application to process and push it to another topic.
4. Finally a bokeh application to pick data from the above topic and display the live graph.

Can anyone suggest a good clean architecture for the same.

Here are the thing that I have done with kafka: written a simple kafka producer,consumer and streaming application in java

But here are the things I am stuck with :

If I am using API's how do the API's communicate with the running kafka producer application, so that it can pass the data which the producers needs to publish to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Kafka REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html) from Confluent. Whilst you're there have a look at [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), or [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/). KSQL runs on top of Kafka Streams, and gives you a very simple way to do streams processing.